# I have Ubuntu 13 and I want 12 back! 13 won't boot my ubuntu 12 dvd during resarting

Tags: installation, boot, uninstall

I installed 13 fine with no problems from a dvd, but now that i can't get jack to work on here i want 12 back very badly. I have it on a disk but I cant get the newest version of Ubuntu to recognize it.... any help is appriciated

Comment: Firstly, just to sate my curiosity, what problems are you having with 13.04 that make you want to roll back? Secondly, if you're trying to do an installation from within Ubuntu itself, you're going about it the wrong way. You should boot off the 12.xx DVD and do a fresh installation.

Comment: Ubuntu is not designed to roll back.  You can get a 12.04 download from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).  You need to do a fresh install by booting from the DVD or bootable USB.  So back-up first because you will lose your personal files and will need to restore them from the backup.

Comment: Please provide us with more information about how JACK doesn't work so that we might suggest something in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why your computer boots up your Ubuntu 13.x DVD and not your 12.x DVD. It most certainly doesn't have anything to do with the currently installed OS.

Maybe your 12.x DVD is so badly scratched that it won't boot anymore? Try to burn a new DVD. Then boot from it.

Comment: i want 12 back because i cant get jack to work in 13, :/ i either want 12 back or to get jack to work (because i use rakarrrak and audacity)